# What does "minimum possible force" imply for this variable-mass system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I recently came across a question as follows

[image]

> A conveyor belt collects sand and transports it to a height h as shown in the figure. The sand falls on the belt with negligible speed at constant rate u (mass per unit time). Friction between the belt and the sand particle is so high that the sand particles stop sliding almost instantaneously after they hit the belt. Acceleration due to gravity is g.
> What should speed of the belt be for the least possible driving force on the belt applied by the motor?

I tried a lot to apply the Merchersky's equation (Ref. I E Irodov) for the variable mass system but I was unable to do so.

My understanding:

The sand falls on the conveyor belt and sticks to it. This slows down the conveyor belt and an external force has to do some work on it to maintain the constant speed.

But I was unable to use  the condition 'minimum possible force'. What does this condition imply about the system in the physical sense?